# Edge detection kernel in java

Tags: java, image-processing, edge-detection

I am a beginner in image processing and I am implementing an edge detecting kernel in java using the kernel given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) but my implementation doesn't seem to work. Please help me rectify the error.
Below is my code

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException{
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("rachel.jpg"));
        int x = image.getWidth();
        int y = image.getHeight();
        for(int i=1;i<x-1;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<y-1;j++){
                int p=0,a=0,r=0,g=0,b=0;
                for(int k=-1;k<2;k++){
                    for(int l=-1;l<2;l++){
                        if(k==0 && l==0){
                            p = image.getRGB(i+k,j+l);
                            r += 8*((p>>16) & 0xFF);
                            g += 8*((p>>8) & 0xFF);
                            b += 8*(p & 0xFF);
                            continue;
                        }
                        p = image.getRGB(i+k,j+l);
                        r -= ((p>>16) & 0xFF);
                        g -= ((p>>8) & 0xFF);
                        b -= (p & 0xFF);
                    }
                }
                r = Math.min(255,r);
                r = Math.max(0,r);
                g = Math.min(255,g);
                g = Math.max(0,g);
                b = Math.min(255,b);
                b = Math.max(0,b);
                a = (image.getRGB(i,j)>>24) & 0xFF;
                p = (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;
                image.setRGB(i,j, p);
            }
        }
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("newrachel.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're storing back the pixels you modify to the original image, before you are done completely processing it.  Of course this will mess up the original image and the calculations you make from it.  Make a second image and store the result to that.

Comment: Thanks, it works now